# Ставиться ли тире

Tags: пунктуация, бсп

Нe знаeшь лично - не сyди публично.

Comment: Тире: alt+0151. Не сложно.

Comment: Нет, тире не ставиться - оно ставится.

Answer (score 3):

Нe знаeшь лично - не сyди публично. Сравнить: Если не знаешь лично, то не суди публично.

Из Правил Лопатина:  Тире в БСП ставится, ели если в первой части предложения есть указание на время или **условие** совершения действия, обозначенного во второй части, например: Зайдешь в такую избушку зимой — жилым духом не пахнет (Шукш.).

Comment: Действия, обозначенного во второй части, например: Зайдешь в такую избушку зимой — жилым духом не пахнет? ======= Не пахнет действием...

Comment: Это цитата и примеры из Лопатина. Что касается действия, то это условное обобщенное название процессуального признака, то есть признака, существующего во времени.

Comment: Тогда бы было так по логике: «или условие совершения действия, обозначенное во второй части»